# shuffle vector within groups, preserving order

Tags: r, permutation, shuffle

I have a vector:

```
x = {x1, x2, x3, ..., xn}
```

And some groups:

```
g = {g1, g2, g3, ..., gn}
```

I want to shuffle the vector elements within each group, but preserve the original group ordering. For example:

```
x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
g = c('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b')
```

Good solution:

```
shuffled_x = c(3, 5, 1, 4, 2)
shuffled_g = c('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b')
```

Bad solution:

```
shuffled_x = c(3, 1, 4, 5, 2)
shuffled_g = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b')
```

I already know how to shuffle within the groups:

```
y = tapply(x, g, sample)
```

Just not sure how to keep them in the correct order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `ave` would shuffle between elements maintaining the group :

```
ave(x, g, FUN = sample)
#[1] 1 4 3 5 2

ave(x, g, FUN = sample)
#[1] 3 4 1 2 5

ave(x, g, FUN = sample)
#[1] 3 2 1 4 5
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I looked at the source code for "ave", but I don't understand the "split(x, g) <- " assignment. Can you explain what is going on here?

Comment: Basically `ave` splits `x` according to groups (here `g`), so in our case it would have two groups (1, 3) and (2, 4, 5) and then applies the function mentioned in the `FUN` argument (here `sample`) to each group separately and returns them same as original length of `x`. This is what I understand, I may not be completely right.

Comment: @RonakShah, this is awesome. Base R never ceases to amaze me.

Comment: @RonakShah I don't understand how the assignment "split(x, g) <- lapply(split(x, g), FUN)" works. How does the lapply statement directly modify "x" within the split(x, g) statement?